# Looking for a smart if condition - Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to make a function to buy item but I dont want people to be able to gather more than 2 items at the same time.

I am looking for a condition that state something like.

if Axe + Sword = true then calling the function `buyItem(Dagger)` will say something like "You cant have more than 2 items".

But consider I want to add more items later.

```
var buyItem = function (name)
{
    if (name === "Axe")
    {
        console.log("Axe");
    }
    else if (name === "Sword")
    {
        console.log("Sword");

    }
    else if (name === "Dagger")
    {
        console.log("Dagger");
    }
};
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store bought count as private variable

```js
// store reference to your function returned from self invoking anonymous function enclosure (to prevent internal vairables from leaking into global scope)
var buyItem = (function(){
  // store local reference to number of items already bought
  var bought = 0;
  // return the function to be assigned to buyItem
  return function (name)
  {
    // if we reached the maximum, don't buy any more - just log a warning and return
    if(bought >= 2){
      console.log("your hands are full!!");
      return;
    } else {
      // otherwise increment the bought counter
      bought++;
    };
    if (name === "Axe")
    {
        console.log("Axe");
    }
    else if (name === "Sword")
    {
      console.log("Sword");
    }
    else if (name === "Dagger")
    {
      console.log("Dagger");
    }
  };
})();

// try it out
buyItem('Dagger');
buyItem('Sword');
buyItem('Axe');
```

Answer (score 1):

How about having a variable that keeps track of how many items you have?

```
int itemsHeld = 0;
```

When you acquire a new item use `itemsHeld++;` and when you lose one use `itemsHeld--;`

Now when trying to get a new item you can just ask `if (itemsHeld < 2) getItem();`